# Macro URL Link to update spreadsheet cell on row where id = 1000

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a task in Google App Script to change a columns cell on the row where the uniqueid column equals the string.

So when I submit a form it adds the record to the sheet then it sends an email asking the user to approve or deny the row. I've seen in some examples they use a macro link for example:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyfg_rXkkDooF-uSlSsqDxZKjDnpmBmQjyepc4g2BnqqM--z2Sg/exec?i=2ffa33e1-a7f3-48a1-f0d8-4dbf194af881&state=APPROVED

is it possible to do it this way so I can have the approve and deny links on the email. I have a macro setup to find the row and change the column value:

```
function Approved(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const s = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
const r = s.getRange('A1:ZZ');
const [hA, ...v] = r.getValues();
const searchTerm = '0c27376a-be23-4d78-a181-9957836bc0c7'; //EMAIL NEEDS TO CAPTURE THIS 
BEFORE CHANGING IT
let col = {};
hA.forEach((h,i) => col[h] = i+1);
for (var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
 if (v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > +1) {
   Logger.log('ROW:' + Number(i + 1));
   s.getRange( i + 2, col['Approval'] ).setValue('Approved')
 }
 }
};
```

Comment: I think I understand but there are some parts that I am not clear on the flow. So the user fills a form, the form submission ends up as a row in the spreadsheet, this would also cause an email to be sent (with what information exactly?), which will contain a link that when pressed will either leave the row as-is, or delete the row? Does each row have a unique identifier? What do you mean by `EMAIL NEEDS TO CAPTURE THIS`?

Comment: What it was called in the question "macro link" it's actually a web app link. To learn the pretty basics of creating web apps in Google Apps Script please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web